# Best output format for storing outputs colllected after batch

Tags: python, list, numpy, pytorch

I have a pre-trained segmentation network which takes in a `(batch_size,5,224,224)` Tensor and outputs a `(batch_size,224,224)` feature vector, say `batch_features`, originally a Torch tensor but can be converted to numpy array.

There are multiple ways to collect the torch tensor.

*Option A : Use a list*

```
val_features = []
val_features.extend(list(batch_features)
```

***Option B : Use a numpy array*

```
val_features = np.empty()
val_features = [*val_features, *batch_features]
```

At the end, I want to iterate through all these arrays and do some post-processing. Which data format would work best in that case?

Comment: both should work fine if you just want to iterate with an explicit loop... however loops are slow in python so it might be a good idea to avoid them and use preexisting array operations. For that numpy arrays would be better but check first if what you want to do is possible in numpy tensor manipulations / operations

Comment: why don't you use batch_features.cpu().numpy()?